# Symfony 3 form - what is ::class and where is name?

Tags: php, symfony

What does the **::class** used in the forms Symfony 3?

For example:

```
->add('task', TextType::class)
```

or

```
$form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);
```

Where can I read about the method **::class**?

In Symfony2 was:

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'appbundle_task';
}
```

And next in view I had prefix, for example:

```
<input id="appbundle_task_name" type="text" name="appbundle_task[name]">
```

What it is now the principle of generating names in inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::class` is used for class name resolution. With that you can get the fully qualified name of the class (FQCN). You can read about that in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class).

Before Symfony 3 you had to passing type instances directly to `FormBuilder::add`, `Form::add` or the `FormFactory`. Now you need to pass the fully-qualified type class name instead, and you can do that with `::class`.

The `getName()` of the form types are no longer needed, as they are now identified by their FQCN. If you want to customize the block prefix of a type in Twig, you should add `getBlockPrefix`.

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'appbundle_task';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now field prefix is without namespace. Is possible to change fields prefix?

Comment: Thanks @Federkun! After an upgrade to symfony v3+, this fixed the **id** & **name** attributes of my form elements.